# Link ManyToManyFields in django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have models defined as below:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    subject_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    teacher_age = models.IntegerField()
    teacher_doj = models.DateField()
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)

class TeacherScores(models.Model):
    co_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length=5)
    internal_score = models.IntegerField()
    external_score = models.IntegerField()
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)
```

Few DB entries are shown below

**Teacher**

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| teacher_id | teacher_name | teacher_age | teacher_doj |
+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| AC23001    | Tina         |          32 | 2017-04-10  |
| AC23002    | Rina         |          31 | 2009-04-10  |
| AC23003    | Tom          |          35 | 2009-04-10  |
| AC23004    | Henry        |          56 | 2009-04-10  |
+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Subjects**

```
+------------+--------------+
| subject_id | subject_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | English      |
|          2 | Hindi        |
|          3 | Sanskrit     |
|          4 | Math         |
|          5 | Physics      |
|          6 | Chemistry    |
|          7 | Biology      |
|          8 | History      |
|          9 | Civics       |
|         10 | Geography    |
|         11 | MoralScience |
|         12 | Algebra      |
+------------+--------------+
```

**teacher_subject**

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | teacher_id | subject_id |
+----+------------+------------+
|  4 | AC23002    |          4 |
|  5 | AC23002    |          8 |
|  2 | AC23002    |         12 |
|  6 | AC23003    |          5 |
|  7 | AC23003    |          9 |
| 10 | AC23004    |          5 |
|  8 | AC23005    |          9 |
|  9 | AC23005    |         10 |
| 11 | AC23006    |         12 |
| 12 | AC23007    |          6 |
| 13 | AC23008    |          6 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Basically I want to add entries to the TeacherSCores model for a particular teacher per subject that he/she handles.
Here I want to modify the TeacherScores model such that I can include scores for a teacher per subject.
I tried inserting subjects via the teacherscores object but I get error.

```
>>> t1 =  TeacherScores('C006','23','24',teacher__subject='Math')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 572, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'teacher__subject' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>>> t1 =  TeacherScores('C006','23','24',teacher__subjects='Math')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 572, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'teacher__subjects' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

How can change my Model- **TeacherScores** to include the **subject field** for a teacher provided there is a ManyToMany field defined between teacher and subject, also with TeacherScores and Teacher

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to create explicit `TeacherSubject` class used to model M2M relationship between `Teacher` and `Subject`. Then you can reference it in `TeacherScores`.

#### 1. Model M2M `Teacher`-`Subject` relation using `through` option:

```
class TeacherSubject(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # extra fields ...
```

and then modify `Teacher` and `TeacherScores` to use `TeacherSubject`:

```
# Teacher:

subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, through=TeacherSubject)

# TeacherScores:

teachersubject = models.ForeignKey(TeacherSubject)
```

#### 2. Explicitly reference `TeacherSubject`:

```
t1 =  TeacherScores('C006','23','24', teachersubject=some_teachersubject_instance)
```

Details are described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Thank you. I will modify my models to include the TeacherSubject model. Apart from the subject, I also want to access the teacher attributes through the TeacherScores model. So is `teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)` also required there? or should it just be defined as a **foreign key**.

Comment: No, it would be better (according to SSoT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)) if you would reference Teacher from TeacherScore via teachersubject.teacher, for example: teacher = teacherscore.teachersubject.teacher, since TeacherSubject holds refernece to Teacher anyway.